# HTML(?) Background slider is adding # anchors to URL in address bar... how do I stop it?

Tags: html, css

I have a page with Superslides. It's a jQuery slider that fills the entire background of the page.

I have a problem. Every time the image updates, the URL in the address bar changes. (When the first image shows, the URL changes to http://…/index.html#1 ... the URL then changes for the next image: http://…/index.html#2 )

How can I stop the URL in the address bar from changing?

I'm completely stumped on this one. Any ideas?

Comment: You could include, or at least link, the code of that plugin.

Comment: I would start by checking the documentation for that plugin.

Comment: You can find the documentation [here](https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about [this plugin](http://nicinabox.com/superslides/).

You must use the option `hashchange: false`, which is its default value.

If you are initializing it like this:

```
$('#slides').superslides({
    slide_easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
    slide_speed: 800,
    pagination: true,
    hashchange: true, // <-- Remove this line
    scrollable: true
});
```

you must remove `hashchange: true`.

You can see the full list of options and what they do in [plugin's github page](https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides#options).

Comment: Thanks. Too obvious to miss! I need to sleep more.